# How to rephrase and simplify a title? Need help with sentence structure

Tags: creative-writing, academic-writing, word-choice, titles, sentence-structure

I have the following title:

> Why drinking from a glass bottle is better than drinking from a glass
> cup at work?

I meant to say that there are lots of benefits to drinking from a glass bottle such that is safer since it's harder to spill water on your electronics. I am looking for ways to shorten this sentence and to make my message more clear.

I am trying to come up with a good title.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your sentence is a question.  Phrase it as one: "Why is drinking from a glass bottle better than drinking from a glass cup at work?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just "Bottle v. Cup".

Don't put your conclusion into the title.

At work, maybe a bottle is better because of electronics, at a dining table, maybe a cup is better.

But I don't care, I am not drinking hot coffee from a bottle, and I drink hot coffee at my desk every morning. In the afternoon I drink soda from a can.

And both of these, and a bottle, are still threats to my technology (and papers on my desk) if knocked over.

I'd suggest you address all sides of the argument.

The title just introduces the topic you will be talking about. **Not your conclusions.**

The body of the paper is where you outline the options and issues, then present your arguments, and then finally present your conclusions.